# How to change one url suffix to another in apache?

Tags: apache, apache2

I hope I can explain this clearly enough, but if not let me know and I'll try to clarify.

I need to configure apache to redirect from one url to another e.g. mySite.com/**maven2** should redirect to mySite.com/**content/maven2**. Do you have any idea how I should do this?

Comment: Do you mean mod-rewrite instructions in .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

In php you can do this with:

```
header("LOCATION: mySite.com/content/maven2");
```

Or you can use a meta refresh...

Comment: If you do a header you'll likely want to add ob_start() to the top of your page as well as ob_flush_end() at the end; this assures that all headers are sent before anything is output to the page, thus stopping headers from being sent.

Comment: I must do it changing configuration in apache2.conf file.

Comment: Not sure you're going to get much help on this one... I have no idea... only thing I can think of... like I said is to redirect it using a script on the server itself. Or use an .htaccess method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) Apache directive.

```
Redirect /maven2 http://example.com/content/maven2
```

You can use that in either .htaccess or httpd.conf